# Solving a quasilinear elliptic pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-operators

For my research, I would like to solve the equation 
$$\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x \partial y}= u\big(f(x,y)\big)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},$$
where $u$ is a generic function of $f(x,y)$.

Please, does anyone know if an explicit representation of the solution $f(x,y)$ exists? In general, I'm interested in characterizing $f(x,y)$.

Comment: This is a hyperbolic equation, no? (Change variables to $x+y,x-y.$) Anyway, I am extremely skeptical that there could be an explicit solution, especially without an explicit $u$.